# Crypto++ RSA key size limitation

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I would like to limit the keys size used in the Crypto++ to 256 bit. The only thing that I found in the code that contains the keyword key is the variable `aKeySize`, which by analogy, I've found that it is the number of characters of the digest.

This is where I have copied my program [a link](http://marko-editor.com/articles/cryptopp_sign_string/).

How to define the limit of 256 bits only for the RSA pair keys?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to define the key size used in cruptopp( private&public keys)

Comment: What are you trying to solve with reducing the RSA key pair length to only 256 bits? The security of a 256 bit RSA key pair is so week that it's not even "allowed" in some implementations.

Comment: I might be able to program my MSX-2 computer so crack 256 bit RSA. I mean the updated Lenstra equations require a key size of 427 bits to be secure all up to 1984 (approx. the time my parents bought our first computer - for me and my brother) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to define the limit of 256 bits only for the RSA pair keys?

From your test program in the [link](http://marko-editor.com/articles/cryptopp_sign_string/):

```
int main(int, char **) {
  auto keys = RsaGenerateHexKeyPair(3072);
  std::cout << "Private key: " << std::endl << keys.privateKey << "\n" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Public key: " << std::endl << keys.publicKey << "\n" << std::endl;
  ...
}
```

You should change `RsaGenerateHexKeyPair(3072)` to:

```
auto keys = RsaGenerateHexKeyPair(256);
```

---

If you want to change it in the Crypto++ library, then modify `GenerateRandom` to throw an `InvalidArgument` exception if `bits` is greater than 256.

`GenerateRandomWithKeySize` is part of a base class deep in the bowels of Crypto++. It is implemented in [`cryptlib.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptlib.cpp), and its body is:

```
void GeneratableCryptoMaterial::GenerateRandomWithKeySize(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, unsigned int keySize)
{
    GenerateRandom(rng, MakeParameters("KeySize", (int)keySize));
}
```

So you need to modify `GenerateRandom` in [`rsa.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/rsa.cpp):

```
void InvertibleRSAFunction::GenerateRandom(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const NameValuePairs &alg)
{
    int modulusSize = 2048;
    alg.GetIntValue(Name::ModulusSize(), modulusSize) || alg.GetIntValue(Name::KeySize(), modulusSize);

    CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(modulusSize >= 16);
    if (modulusSize < 16)
        throw InvalidArgument("InvertibleRSAFunction: specified modulus size is too small");

    m_e = alg.GetValueWithDefault(Name::PublicExponent(), Integer(17));

    CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(m_e >= 3); CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(!m_e.IsEven());
    if (m_e < 3 || m_e.IsEven())
        throw InvalidArgument("InvertibleRSAFunction: invalid public exponent");

    RSAPrimeSelector selector(m_e);
    AlgorithmParameters primeParam = MakeParametersForTwoPrimesOfEqualSize(modulusSize)
        (Name::PointerToPrimeSelector(), selector.GetSelectorPointer());
    m_p.GenerateRandom(rng, primeParam);
    m_q.GenerateRandom(rng, primeParam);

    m_d = m_e.InverseMod(LCM(m_p-1, m_q-1));
    CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(m_d.IsPositive());

    m_dp = m_d % (m_p-1);
    m_dq = m_d % (m_q-1);
    m_n = m_p * m_q;
    m_u = m_q.InverseMod(m_p);   
}
```

---

> but the keys still so big ... (From an earlier comment)

256-bit RSA is usually considered too small. It is well within reach of ordinary people.

You should consider switching to Elliptic Curves. If you fix the curve and use a compressed public point then you can get a fairly small key, like on the order of 32-bytes for secp256.

Comment: thank you @jww I have already tried but i am still confused  because the last generated private key is of length 369 which mean 369* 4 bit

Comment: Also see [Keys and Formats | RSA Private key](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#RSA_PrivateKey) on the Crypto++ wiki. There are 11 fields encoded in a RSA private key.

Comment: CryptoPP is a software only implementation afaik. Anybody can still work around the *extremely stupid* limitation by generating the key pairs themselves. The question is non-sensical. The proposed solution may be correct, but without the question pointing out why the question is stupid and why the limitation doesn't make sense, I cannot agree with it.

Comment: @Maarten - Yeah, these are some unusual requirements. I _think_ OP needs either (1) block or stream cipher, or (2) a short signature scheme, but we don't have enough information to suggest something different.